# How to find parameters for ridge and lasso regularization when cost minimization does not converge?

Tags: logistic, lasso, ridge-regression, convergence

In the Stanford ML course, we were taught to find good values for the lambda parameters of ridge/lasso by iterating for various lambda values on several cross-validation sets and picking the values which correspond to the hypothesis with the minimum CV error.

The problem is, I am playing with a big data set (which might not even be well suited for logistic regression (??): [Internet Ads set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Internet+Advertisements)) and I can't use the method described above because, during optimization, the cost stays stable (changes only around the 8th decimal place between iterations) and doesn't seem to converge.

I need good values for the regularization in order to converge, but I can't converge without the aforementioned good values.

Any suggestions? Should I move on to using SVM, or is this data set solvable with logistic regression?

NB: I am doing this for learning purposes, so I'm much more interested in explanations why my approach is bad than I am in black-box libraries which will give me a solution.

**EDIT: Some relevant code snippets (occasionally pseudocode-ish, for clarity). The usual notations apply.**

The function used to compute the cost:

```
def computeCost(theta, X, y):
    global iter
    iter += 1
    if iter > 10:
        raise TooManyIterationsException(iter) # Because the cost doesn't converge, I force interruption in order to jump to another combination of lambda values
    m = y.size
    h = sigmoid(X.dot(theta.T))
    J = y.T.dot(log(h)) + (1.0 - y.T).dot(numpy.log(1.0 - h))
    J_reg2 = theta[1:]**2
    J_reg1 = theta[1:]
    cost = (-1.0 / m) * (J.sum()) + LAMBDA2 * J_reg2.sum() + LAMBDA1 * J_reg1.sum()
    print "Cost: ", cost
    return cost
```

Invoking scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs:

```
initial_thetas = numpy.zeros((len(train_X[0]), 1))
myargs = (train_X, train_y)

for LAMBDA1 in [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, ..., 10]:
    for LAMBDA2 in my_range[0.01, 0.02, 0.04, ..., 10]:
        try:
            iter = 0
            theta = scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(computeCost, x0=initial_thetas, args=myargs)            
        except TooManyIterationsException as e:
            print '\n'
```

A typical output looks like this:
[image]

**EDITED AGAIN: Evolution of thetas!** 
[image]

Comment: How is it possible that your cost is not changing? The only thing I can think of is that your lambda values aren't actually different. Maybe posting code for what you have done will help to see if your situation can be re-created.

Comment: @idris I have tried manually various combinations of lambdas, but the cost is always the same. In the meantime, I have found a couple other secondary issues with my implementation; if after fixing them I'm still having problems, I'll post the relevant parts of my code here.

Comment: @idris Added source code, as well as an output example. Thanks!

Comment: @Denis I'm not sure what you meant by +/- 1-5%... shall I increase/reduce each of my thetas by those percents and use cost with them modified? By the way, updated my post -- there's an interesting trend in the thetas. The value in theta[0] is shifted in the next cost computation to theta[1], then to theta[2], and so on. I'm not sure whether this is relevant, since I don't know the details of fmin_bfgs implementation.

Comment: @Denis Aha, now I understand! Thank you, this kind of debugging suggestion is invaluable -- I'll check it out!

Comment: @Denis Thank you very much for all the pointers! I have some more ideas now, let's see where I get stuck next :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the question "why is cost() so flat near [0 0 0 0] ?",
or "why does fmin_xx not find a minimum on a flat surface ?"
A couple of suggestions anyway:

1) look at cost() near x0,
with `look( f, x0, h )` -> f() at all corners of a cube of side 2h around x0,
or if that's too many at a random subset.
2) is [0 0 0 0] a reasonable start point for weights ?
3) what happened to the first 3, continuous, columns of X ?
4) start with `fmin()` a.k.a. Nelder-Mead
(at the best dim + 1 points from `look()`)
before running fmin_xx -- more powerful but harder to drive.
5) [scikit-learn SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/modules/sgd.html) got to

```
97.3 % correct  SGDClassifier  uciml/ad*
    X (1572, 1558) Xtest (787, 1558)  -- 2/3, 1/3 split
    centre 3  -- scale all feature columns to [-1, 1]
    sgditer 100  loss log  penalty l2
11 sec
Confusion matrix: 97.3 % correct = 766 / 787
True classes down, estimated across  / true class sizes
0:  652    8  /  660  99 %
1:   13  114  /  127  90 %
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra suggestions and for all the effort you've put into my question! I feel smarter than I was a week ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have two $\lambda$ values. In all the logistic regression I've encountered, there is only one $\lambda$ value, and you try different values of $\lambda$ to minimize the cost $J$. I also took the machine learning class you reference, and my Octave code looked like this.

```
J = 1/m * sum(-y' * log(sigmoid(X*theta)) - (1-y)'*log(1-sigmoid(X*theta)));
J += lambda/(2*m) * sum(theta(2:theta_len,:).^2);
```

Note that lambda should be a scalar value in this implementation.

This is the math equivalent of the above Octave statement.

$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^m[y^{(i)}log(h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})) - (1-y^{(i)})log(1-h_{\theta}(x^{(i)}))] + \frac{\lambda}{2m}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\theta^{2}_{j}$

Comment: What we did there was ridge regression. Based on previous suggestions in another post, I was trying to implement here [elastic net regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization), which is a combination of ridge and lasso methods. Hence, I need lambda2 for ridge, and lambda1 for lasso.

Comment: Ok, this is out of my wheel house as I am not yet familiar with elastic net. I do notice your (\theta) look to be pretty much all zero. Might be something work looking at.

Comment: Yeah, I have a couple of directions I want to follow now, the thetas are only one of them. Thanks a lot for the idea-bouncing! :-)